# Not able to scroll to specific element in Msite - Chrome browser - Appium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, appium, android, mobile-automation

I have implemented scroll in mobile device with appium. Whenever I am scrolling to some element it is not scrolling properly.

Tried with fixed scroll points as well. Here problem is I have small , medium and large size mobile screen sizes available. Which is giving error for other devices.

> Problem statement : Want to resolve run time scroll to some element.

**Example : Want to scroll till : "Shops By Grades"**

---

**Code to scroll :**

`((AppiumDriver) driver).scrollToExact("Text");`

---

> URL : https://www.2gud.com/?cmpid=2G108229

*Note: Please open this URL in mobile device and verify.*

Comment: try with scrollTo("text");

Comment: I tried that as well.. Did you check the website in mobile ? I think that is not text. can u please check once ?